# NextJS Inherit Query Param From Previous Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make the param from current url are pass to the next url when router change. for example:

**My current url:** `localhost:3000/dashboard/?name=abc`

when I move to page /profile for example then I expect the url must be like this:

**Next Url:** `localhost:3000/profile/?name=abc`


I want to pass automatically everytime we move the page even though we didn't include the param when we are pushing the router

If I do this: `router.push("/profile"))`

The result will be: `localhost:3000/profile/?name=abc` if I have query param `name` on the previous router

If anyone can refer me the documentation about it because I can't found it, or if you are have any solution for it. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to "forward" the current query along to the next route path using the URLObject syntax.

Example:

```
const router = useRouter();

...

router.push({
  pathname: "/profile", // <-- new target path
  query: router.query   // <-- any current "queryString"
});
```

Comment: ohh okay, so the only way to do it is by modify every router change by passing the current query? hmm.. I thought there is a way to intercept every query change on the _app file. Anyway many thanks!

Comment: @Potamir Yeah, nothing I am aware of to do this automagically. If you find yourself needing to do this a lot you could abstract the logic into a custom React hook, but you'd still need to use the hook and new "push" function in all the places where you want to retain and forward the query.